# Facebook support for Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, facebook, networking

I'm in a group project for developing a game for facebook.  I did some research on languages to use on both platforms.  What I found on facebook websites and on the forums scattered across the net is that facebook uses flash, javascript, php, and possibly html5 (web is transitioning over).

I haven't found much specific for java and c++ for facebook and I try looking around the support and help center for support on these two languages.  Do you guys know if facebook can support for java and c++?

Comment: @nmagerko Java != Javascript ... they are hardly related...

Comment: Is the structure of the OOPS not the same?

Answer (score 2):

The language is hardly relevant by any miles.

The bare root basics of "Facebook support" is just its REST service endpoints. It doesn't really matter what languages you call them for. So long as the language support:

HTTP Requests,
Json (de)serialisation.

You will be able to integrate with Facebook.

The so called "supported" language are just languages with SDK (Which is just essentially REST service wrappers anyway.). If C++ doesn't have SDK for facebook, just look up the REST api documentation.

found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

There's also a graph api explorer which you can inspect the out going and in coming trafic to try copy cat its request to get you started http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=100002793919270

Lastly, all facebook/google/twitter use OAuth authentication. Again its a platform/language agnostic authentication system consisting of HTTP Post and SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Java has an SDK, plus Spring Social for Facebook and a few Android open source projects